# Error adding a service reference to Visual Studio via WSDL

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, visual-studio-2008, namespaces, wsdl

I have been given a WSDL with all the method requests and responses, and all the objects I'll need to use for creating a few web methods.

I've successfully added the WSDL as a "service reference" and I can see the methods and structures and can instantiate them. It all seems to be there. But, I have a problem: the project won't build after I add the WSDL. Here's the error message I am getting when Visual Studio tries to compile `Reference.cs`:

> "Error 2 The type name 'ServiceReference1' does not exist in the type
>   'WSPELab.WSPELab' C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\WSPELab\WSPELab\Service
>   References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs 21 111 WSPELabSLN

Is it possible that I am receiving this error message because of a namespace error on my part?

Finally, one additional question: With the WSDL added, can I use the structures it contains directly? Or are they just "listings" for me to implement?

Comment: Possibly related: [Error accessing a WCF service from a client](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31357502/1497596)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WSDL is a machine-readable file that describes the methods and types exposed by a web service. Many IDEs, including Eclipse and Visual Studio, can import these and create programming language classes that match the definitions given in the WSDL.

For example, importing a WSDL in a Visual Studio C# project will create a `Reference.cs` file that contains these definitions. You have to instantiate and call these definitions the same as you do for any classes.

```
var webServiceReference = new WsdlNamespace.ClassDefinedInWsdl();
WsdlNamespace.ParamClassDefinedInWsdl dataToGet;
WsdlNamespace.ReturnCodeTypeDefinedInWsdl retCode = webServiceReference.MethodDefinedInWsdl("params expected by method", out dataToGet);
if (retCode == WsdlNamespace.ReturnCodeValueMeaningAllIsWell)
{
    // use properties of dataToGet
}
```

Giving any more detail would require showing us the actual WSDL.

Comment: Thanks! I was going in the right direction but there was some weird namespace error.
I started a new project and added the reference, I can now use all the existing classes.

Thanks again!